# SSAS Cube processing

Tags: ssas, olap-cube

I have deployed my SSAS solution to production. On the production server, I want to process my cube, but when I right click on the ssas cube and choose "Process", I recieve the follwong error:
The 'Database' with 'ID' = 'XXX' doesn't exist in the collection.

Has anyone encountered this error in Microsoft SSAS? If so, can anyone tell me what to do to resove this error ?

Comment: As a first step, I would select the Analysis Services databases folder in Management Studio and press F5 fro refresh. If that does not help, try to disconnect and reconnect from Analysis Services.

Comment: thx but that did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see what the Id of the database is by right clicking on the database and selecting properties.  Check the equivalent in visual studio and confirm it matches.  If you have renamed the analysis services project (maybe for a backup), the id of the database does not get renamed and sometimes gets messed up in the XML file.

Try re-processing the dimensions on their own and then the cube.  Failing that, if this is the first process (i.e. the cube is not live), try deleting and redeploying from visual studio.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-deploy the OLAP database from SSDT with a different name and before you do you just need to change the database name and set the Processing Option to Full. You can set these options under Project's Configuration Properties->Deployment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem. I solved it by editing the roles in my SSAS database :

[image: Right Click properties]

And then, check the boxes depending on what you want your job to do :

[image: Check boxes]

Then, you can process your cubes with your SSIS Jobs.

Answer (score 0):

it can either be roles or kerberos, I got a similar error when the kerberos authentication wasnt setup in the cube server to interact with database server.